# set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration breaks scandinavian characters

Tags: powershell

I've created a powershell script that removes all licences and group memberships from a person when he/she is leaving the company and adds an automatic reply to their mailbox. Everything else is going fine, except when i added Scandinavian letters into the hardcoded auto-reply.
**bold The error is only for hard coded data. Everything that is prompted is read correctly**

```
    if ( "y" -eq $Automaattivastaus) {
    $Username = Read-Host -Prompt "Nimi automaattivastaukseen"
    $Paivamaara = Read-Host -Prompt "Milloin henkilön työsuhde on päättynyt?"
    $Vastaanottaja = Read-Host -Prompt "automaattivastaus, Mihin sähköpostiin ottaa yhteyttä"

    set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $Email -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage  "Henkilön $Username palvelussuhde on päättynyt $Paivamaara. Pyydän kääntymään hänen työtehtäviensä hoitoon liittyvissä asioissa sovelletaan Lakia yksityisyyden suojasta työelämässä (759/2004)."
```

"snippet from auto reply PyydÃ¤n kÃ¤Ã¤ntymÃ¤Ã¤n hÃ¤nen tyÃ¶tehtÃ¤viensÃ¤ hoitoon liittyvissÃ¤ asioissa."
As you can see the characters break. If anyone would have the solution how to fix this I would be grateful.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName "my.account@test.com" -ShowProgress $true
Add-Type -AssemblyName system.web
    
    
$Username = "Täältä pesee! Härifrån tvättas!"
$Paivamaara = "15.06.2021"
$Vastaanottaja = "Öland"
$Email = "test.account@test.com"
    
$Automaattivastaus = "Henkilön $Username palvelussuhde on päättynyt $Paivamaara. Pyydän kääntymään hänen työtehtäviensä hoitoon liittyvissä asioissa 
    ($Vastaanottaja) puoleen. Mikäli viestisi on luonteeltaan yksityisluontainen, pyydän ottamaan yhteyttä suoraan henkilöön $Username. Yksityisluontaiset viestit tuhotaan ilman niiden avaamista. Työhön liittyvien viestien selvittämiseen ja avaamiseen 
    sovelletaan Lakia yksityisyyden suojasta työelämässä (759/2004)."
$t = [web.httputility]::Htmldecode($Automaattivastaus)
set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $Email -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage ([web.httputility]::Htmldecode($t))  -ExternalMessage ([web.httputility]::Htmldecode($t))
```

Comment: Is there any option for setting the charset? The 'broken' text looks like it might be UTF-8 encoding. You might also find https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/0c2a4643-ca4c-49b9-a1bd-6c9fc045d141/oof-umlaute-nicht-richtig-dargestellt?forum=exchange_serverde to be useful (it's in German, so may require translation).

Comment: Also useful might be https://www.msxfaq.de/konzepte/oof.htm#oof__umlaute_und_zeichensatz_us_ascii (also in German).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Exchange available, so I can't check this. Anyway, since [ExternalMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxautoreplyconfiguration?view=exchange-ps) wraps the message automatically within HTML tags, try and convert the string into HTML escaped form. That will escape `åäö` and other characters that need escaping in HTML. Like so,

```
# Load assembly that contains the utility class
add-type -AssemblyName system.web
# A demo string with Finnish and Swedish letters
$s = "Täältä pesee! Härifrån tvättas!"  
# Encode the string.
$t = [web.httputility]::HtmlEncode($s)    
$t
T&#228;&#228;lt&#228; pesee! H&#228;rifr&#229;n tv&#228;ttas!

# The encoding is reversable, obviously.    
[web.httputility]::Htmldecode($t)     
Täältä pesee! Härifrån tvättas!
```

Edit:

Call the ENcode version, it will convert ääkköset into escped forms. the DEcode will reverse the encoding. It is not needed here, and was included as for illustration purposes only. Like so,

```
$Automaattivastaus = "Henkilön $Username palvelussuhde on päättynyt $Paivamaara..."
$encodedAnswer = [web.httputility]::HtmlEncode($Automaattivastaus)
set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $Email -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage $encodedAnswer  -ExternalMessage $encodedAnswer
```

Comment: I'm unsure if I did it correctly but it still gives the same auto-reply. I tried to encode and decode, but both had the same result. Thanks for the answers, just a bit slow to understand.

Comment: @rikisorsa The edit went into my answer, not to the question. Anyway, don't call `HtmlDEcode` when you need `HtmlENcode`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you would enclose the message in quotation marks and set the encoding?

```
$Username = Read-Host -Prompt "Nimi automaattivastaukseen"
$Paivamaara = Read-Host -Prompt "Milloin henkilön työsuhde on päättynyt?"
$Vastaanottaja = Read-Host -Prompt "automaattivastaus, Mihin sähköpostiin ottaa yhteyttä"

$message = "<html><head><meta charset='UTF-8'></head>
<body>
Henkilön $Username palvelussuhde on päättynyt $Paivamaara. Pyydän kääntymään hänen työtehtäviensä hoitoon liittyvissä asioissa sovelletaan Lakia yksityisyyden suojasta työelämässä (759/2004). 
</body>
</html>"

set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration -identity $Email -AutoReplyState Enabled -InternalMessage $message
```

I'm no expert in either PowerShell or Exchange but this might help you.

Comment: ([web.httputility]::Htmlencode($t))  -ExternalMessage ([web.httputility]::Htmlencode($t)) when using Encode the data that is hardcoded still is unreadable, but the data from read-host is fine "Täältä pesee! palvelussuhde on pÃ¤Ã¤ttynyt Härifrån tvättas!. PyydÃ¤n". Täältä pesee! and Härifrån tvättas! are prompted for somehow readable.